# Extract string from char var column and date from same column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following text from a column called 'subject':

```
Standard WiFi Install - (Broadband) by HS&S - Job No:VR041135037 on 2022-01-14
```

I need to extract the ID (`VR041135037`) and the date (`2022-01-14`) from the subject column.

What query can I write to go about doing this?

EDIT: This is the column from the table I have:

| Subject |
| --- |
| OPALS INSTALL by HS&S - Job No:VR041613130 on 2022-03-17 |
| OPALS INSTALL by HS&S - Job No:VR041613130 on 2022-03-17 |
| Standard WiFi Install - (Broadband) by HS&S - Job No:VR041729247 on 2022-03-17 |
| Standard WiFi Install - (Broadband) by HS&S - Job No:VR041729247 on 2022-03-17 |
| OPALS INSTALL by HS&S - Job No:VR041665578 on 2022-03-18 |
| OPALS INSTALL by HS&S - Job No:VR041665578 on 2022-03-18 |

Thanks

Comment: Please add more sample data.

Comment: Hi - Have added in a column I am trying to get this info from if this helps? Let me know if I can add anything else @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using the `SUBSTRING()` function in regex mode with the help of a capture group:

```sql
SELECT
    Subject,
    SUBSTRING(Subject FROM 'Job No:([^[:space:]]+)') AS ID,
    SUBSTRING(Subject FROM '\y[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$') AS date
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, is there somewhere I can read more about the code in green you have outlined? It works perfectly, but would like to know how it works

Answer (score 0):

You could nest `SPLIT_PART` function as well:

```
with my_data as (
  select 'OPALS INSTALL by HS&S - Job No:VR041613130 on 2022-03-17' as col1 union all
  select 'Standard WiFi Install - (Broadband) by HS&S - Job No:VR041729247 on 2022-03-17' union all
  select 'OPALS INSTALL by HS&S - Job No:VR041665578 on 2022-03-18'
  )
select col1,
 split_part(split_part(col1, 'Job No:', 2), ' ', 1) as job, 
 split_part(split_part(col1, 'Job No:', 2), ' on ', 2) as date
from my_data;
```

| col1 | job | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OPALS INSTALL by HS&S - Job No:VR041613130 on 2022-03-17 | VR041613130 | 2022-03-17 |
| Standard WiFi Install - (Broadband) by HS&S - Job No:VR041729247 on 2022-03-17 | VR041729247 | 2022-03-17 |
| OPALS INSTALL by HS&S - Job No:VR041665578 on 2022-03-18 | VR041665578 | 2022-03-18 |

---